# django.db.utils.OperationalError: my_table has no column id error?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I'm testing my models.py file of my Django app: "myapp" in my Python interepreter, but keep running into this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table myapp_table1 has no column named attribute1_id
```

I have 2 tables in my models.py, table1 and table 2.

```
 class table1 (models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
   def __str__(self):             
     return self.name
 class table2 (models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length =25)
   attribute1= models.ForeignKey(Type, related_name = "att1_set+", default=None)
   attribute2= models.ManyToManyField(Type, related_name = "att2_set+", default=None)
   def __str__(self):             
     return self.metric_name
```

In my python interpreter:

```
>>> from my_app.models import table1, table2
>>> t1 = table1 (name = "ty1", id = 0)
>>> t1.save()
>>> t2 = table1 (name = "ty2", id = 1)
>>> e1 = table2 (name = "as", attribute1 = t1)
>>> e1.save() 
>>> error aforementioned after .save
```

However when I exe: "manage.py sql myapp", I see for my table2:

```
CREATE TABLE "my_app_table2" (
"id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
"name" varchar(25) NOT NULL,
"attribute1_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "myapp_table1" ("id")
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to run `python manage.py syncdb` (or `python manage.py migrate` if you use `south` - which you should) in order for changes to be applied to the database.

Comment: When I run "python manage.py migrate" I get: 'django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "my_app_table2_attribute2" 
 already exists'

Comment: @user3423787 Delete everything from your DB and rerun `syncdb` + `migrate`.

Comment: how do you delete everything. I tried to doing "manage.py flush". But same error. Do you literally need to delete the .db file from your top level project directory?

Comment: Thanks so much, its working now. So was the problem that my db was no in synce with models.py? Whenever I make changes to models.py, I need to do both makemigrations and migrate right?

Comment: I'm now testing my "models.py" in tests.py. However, when I run "manage.py test", code defined in the methods (ie def()) of each class is not  executed. But if I move code outside of def but still in each class it is executed

Comment: @user3423787 Yes, you do. StackOverflow permits only one question per thread, so please open up another question for the tests issue. Also, don't forget to mark my answer as accepted (green checkmark) if it answered your question.

Comment: Just did, thanks for your response. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22446617/test-def-code-not-executed

Answer (score 0):

first delete pycache, and all 0001_initial.py, then `python manage.py flush`, then

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

then

```
python manage.py migrate
```

then

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```