# test def() code not executed

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I run "manage.py test" to test my Django models, the code defined in each method (ie def()) of each class is not executed. But if I move code outside of def but still in each class it is executed

Comment: Please be more specific and provide the code.

Comment: The method name has to begin with `test` to be automatically detected and run; are you doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test methods have to be prefixed with "test", this might be the issue. As follows:

```
def test_some_condition(self):
    pass
```